# Eclipse cannot import import com.google.android.maps.*?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-maps

I am trying the google maps api for android, but eclipse does not import the `com.google.android.maps.*` files.

Source:

MyMapActivity:

```
package org.madmax.map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.*;

public class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity {
    private MapView map;
    private MapController controller;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

in the Manifest file I have already declared:

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

How do I import the `com.google.android.maps.*` files?

Comment: you need to add corresponding jar in claaspath .

Comment: where can I find that *.jar? Have you got a link where to download?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not enough to just have the API SDK installed. From the android maps documentation,

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html

If you want to add Maps to an existing application, right-click the project in Package Explorer, choose Properties > Android and then select a build target from the list displayed. You must choose the "Google APIs" build target.

(The standard Android packages don't include Google Maps)

Update, found a screenshot online,  don't pick a Target with the name "Android x.x" pick the corresponding target that says "Google APIs" for the version of Android you want.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the Google APIs installed in your SDK. Open the SDK manager from the `tools` directory and use it to install the package.